# Django doesn't support MySQL Group Replication

Tags: mysql, django, compose-db

I'm using Compose for MySQL which uses [MySQL 5.7 Group Replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-replication-requirements.html)

When trying doing DB tests with Django 1.11.4 i get errors regarding the rollback_test (because it doesn't hold the requirement of Primary Key)

and transaction-write-set-extraction!=OFF requirement for creating SAVEPOINTS.

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1290, 'The MySQL server is running with the --transaction-write-set-extraction!=OFF option so it cannot execute this statement')

Everything works well besides the tests.

Is there any way to tell Django that it's a Group-Replication MySQL DB and avoid these specific tests?

Answer (score 0):

The transaction-write-set-extraction is required for using Group Replication on InnoDB

Versions prior to [MySQL 5.7.19](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-19.html) does not support save points on Group Replication.

Upgrade your local and production MySQL to 5.7.19 or later.

> Replication: Group Replication now supports SQL transaction SAVEPOINT.

As for Django it creates [saves points](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/transactions/#topics-db-transactions-savepoints) when nesting atomic code, so you may encounter this issue in the future outside of your tests.

> When the atomic() decorator is nested, it creates a savepoint to allow partial commit or rollback.

Also you may need to check if your production server is [properly configured](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-innodb-cluster-working-with-production-deployment.html) for InnoDB cluster.

Comment: Yes it's a problem with Compose for MySQL. I just switched to another provider since Django doesn't support it

Comment: Might want to check out Compose now. MySQL 5.7.20 is now available